# How to average over the fourth dimension of a 4-D array in R

Tags: arrays, r

I have a 4-D array in `R` and I want to average my array over the fourth dimension so that it gets reduced to a 3-D array. Is there a simple command to do this or is it faster to just do it inside of a for loop?

For example, imagine I have the following 4-D array `A` and I want some code that would produce the answer in `A.mean`

```
A = array(2,c(3,4,2,2))
A[,,,2] = 3


A.mean = array(2.5,c(3,4,2))
```

Comment: See, also, something like `rowMeans(A, dims = 3)`

Comment: @alexis_laz do you know if rowMeans is faster than using apply?

Comment: `?rowMeans` says it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
apply(A, c(1,2,3), FUN=mean)
```

Comment: Is the apply function faster than using a for-loop when the array is very large?

Comment: @RustyStatistician  `apply` is also a `loop` and may not have that much difference in efficiency, but I find it a bit easier to go through it.